# How do you add a user to a group using Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I am using Apache Directory Studio to set up an initial user on an LDAP partition. I have added the user, and I have a group (Administrators) that I am trying to add that user to.

Users are ou=users and groups are ou=groups and where copied from ou=system. The user was created by adding an inetOrgPerson class entry.

How do I add a user to a group? What kind of class would I use and what attributes are required?

I feel I am missing a lot of information with LDAP. I got this far by ghacking (googling and hacking - the least efficient thing you can do). So, where do I go that will tell me what to do and how to get it done in a cook-book style guide, or at least some sort of detailed reference on the classes and schemas that would define what each is used for

Any help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Select your group
2. Right Click on the right side and select "new attribute"

[image: Right Click and select new attribute]

3. Type member and/or select from list

[image: selecting attribute type]

4. Hit the browse button and search for your user or enter the path
5. Hit OK button

[image: DN Editor]

Comment: How would I go about adding permissions to a group that I have created?
I created 2 new groups and added users to those groups but those users are unable to query the groups to which they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Directory Studio you can interactively add a user to e.g. a groupOfNames entry by adding a value (Ctrl++) to the multivalued attribute member.  Studio comes with a DN value editor which allows you to browse the Directory Information Tree for the user to add.

As for the objectClass to use for groups and users, you should consult the relevant RFC's (e.g. 4519).  For a more prosaic lecture there are a couple of good books (e.g. Howe: Understanding and Deploying LDAP Directory Services).